# Search Box Results Allow Me To Click To Another Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const people = [
    {name: 'tax overview'},
    
    {name: 'patel'}
];
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}


const list = document.getElementById('list');
function setList(group) {
    clearList();
    for (const person of group){
        const item = document.createElement('li')
        item.classList.add('list-group-item');
        const text = document.createTextNode(person.name.capitalize());
        item.appendChild(text);
        
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
    if (group.length === 0){
        setNoResults();
    }
}

function clearList(){
   while (list.firstChild){
       list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
   } 
}
function setNoResults(){
    const item= document.createElement('li')
    item.classList.add('list-group-item');
    const text = document.createTextNode("No results found")
    item.appendChild(text);
    list.appendChild(item); 
}
function getRelevancy(value, searchTerm) {
    if (value === searchTerm) {
        return 2;
        
    }else if(value.startsWith(searchTerm)){
        return 1;
    }else if (value.includes(searchTerm)){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search');
searchInput.addEventListener('input' , (event) => {
    let value = event.target.value;
    if (value && value.trim().length > 0){
        value = value.trim().toLowerCase();
        setList(people.filter(person => {
            
            return person.name.includes(value);
        }).sort((personA, personB) => {
            return getRelevancy(personB.name, value) -getRelevancy(personA.name, value);  
        }));
    }else{
        clearList();
    }
    
});
```

```html
    <div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
        <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
<input autofocus placeholder="Search Topics" class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="search" id="search" />
    <ul class="list-group" id="list"></ul>
</div>

    
</div>
```

I want the search results to take me to another link, like a file. For example I search Tax Overview, then it takes me to taxoverview.html. Another minor problem is that since my search bar is in the navbar, when it displays the results, it pushs my navbar all the way down, and its pretty annoying. Is there anyway to make the results go over the screen and content instead of pushing everything down? Thanks, and any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just make that element an `anchor` tag and provide the `href`

Comment: How do you do that?